VC dimension of indicator of convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$
I'm not understanding the proof of the VC dimension of the set of indicators of convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ having the VC dimension of $\infty$.
All arguments say that for any $n$ points on the unit circle, we can realize any label by the convex hull of the points we want to label as $1$.

But I'm not seeing how the argument generalizes.
In particular, how do we realize the label for this one?

If we use the same convex hull, we would end up assigning the blue dot as $1$, which we don't want.
Thank you.

I do not understand the issue. Any set of points on the unit circle generates a convex hull; the convex hull consists of the points on the unit circle and a set of points inside the unit circle. This convex hull does not contain any other points on the unit circle. So, by definition, the convex hull of the blue points does not contain any red points.

@TedBlack but I want to label the blue points as 0, and if the blue points are in the convex hull, it's labelled as 1 no?

Convex sets in $\mathbb R^2$ have a VC dimension of $\infty$  on the unit circle.
